# TCL multi-character split in Python?

Tags: python, split, scripting, tcl

I am splitting a text file using this tcl proc:

```
proc mcsplit "str splitStr {mc {\x00}}" {
return [split [string map [list $splitStr $mc] $str] $mc]  }

# mcsplit --
#   Splits a string based using another string
# Arguments:
#   str       string to split into pieces
#   splitStr  substring
#   mc        magic character that must not exist in the orignal string.
#             Defaults to the NULL character.  Must be a single character.
# Results:
#   Returns a list of strings
```

The `split` command splits a string based on each character that is in the `splitString`. This version handles the `splitString` as a combined string, splitting the string into constituent parts,
but my objective is to do the same using python does anyone here did the same before?

Comment: How is this different from [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)?

Comment: The `split` method on a string splits based on the substring (as a combined string), it does not split on each character. It seems like this is the behaviour you want? `"abbc".split("bb") => ['a', 'c']`

Comment: str.split()  worked fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear from your question whether the python `split` behavior is what you need. If you need to split at each occurrence of a multiple-character string, Python's regular `split` will do the job:

```py
>>> 'this is a test'.split('es')
['this is a t', 't']
```

If, however, you want to split at any occurrence of multiple *individual* characters, you'll need to use `re.split`:

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'[es]', 'this is a test')
['thi', ' i', ' a t', '', 't']
>>>
```